# How to plot a horizontal quadratic function?

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a "sideways" or horizontal quadratic function in R but am running into the issue of having `sqrt(-x)` which is a problem of course.

```
eq1 = function(x){ -60*(sqrt(1-x)-1) }
eq2 = function(x){ 60*(sqrt(1-x)+1) }

plot(eq1, 0, 100, add=TRUE, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,100))
plot(eq2, 0, 100, add=TRUE)
```

Here is an example of the output plot

[image]

And the output from the R Console:

```
> eq1 = function(x){ -60*(sqrt(1-x)-1) }
> eq2 = function(x){ 60*(sqrt(1-x)+1) }
> 
> 
> plot(eq1, 0, 100, add=TRUE, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,100))
Warning messages:
1: In curve(expr = x, from = from, to = to, xlim = xlim, ylab = ylab,  :
  'add' will be ignored as there is no existing plot
2: In sqrt(1 - x) : NaNs produced
> plot(eq2, 0, 100, add=TRUE)
Warning message:
In sqrt(1 - x) : NaNs produced
```

If I understand correctly, there are domain restrictions on a quadratic function like this. If so, is there a way to incorporate them into the function as defined in R? Or is there are better way to go about drawing this function?

Comment: Shouldn't the first `plot` have `add = FALSE`?

Comment: Yes, that would be more correct and remove that warning. I took this code snippet out of a larger project however where I am trying to draw this function on top of a scatter plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correctly define the range you want to plot the function on with the `x` argument to `plot.function`:

```
plot(eq1, seq(0, 1, 0.01), xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,100))
plot(eq2, seq(0, 1, 0.01), add=TRUE)
```

Actually, `plot.function` is smart enough that even without a range it will fix that for you:

```
plot(eq1, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,100))
plot(eq2, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

(With no warnings.)

Comment: oh nice! ..I see..this is what OP  wanted .

Answer (score 1):

Unless I missed something..why not use `abs`:

```
eq1 = function(x){ -60*(sqrt(abs(1-x))-1) }
eq2 = function(x){ 60*(sqrt(abs(1-x))+1) }



plot(eq1, 0, 100, add=FALSE, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,100))
plot(eq2, 0, 100, add=TRUE)
```